# Step response of voltage inverter and RC filter homework question

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transient, step-response

[image]

This is my solution so far:

- Vth would simply be the output of the inverting op amp which is **Vth = -(Rf/Ri)Vi**
- Rth would simply be R2 || R3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4obUZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And now we have a simple RC circuit with a DC source. So at t = inf, its right to assume that the capacitor would just charge to the V of its source. Am I right?

And then the step response would be:

- Using the total response formula of an RC circuit (wouldn't go to all the derivation)

**V(t) = (V(0) - V(steady-state))e^(1/RC) + V(steady-state)**

- Tau would just be C x (R2 || R3)

So the step response would look like

V(t) = (0 - Vth)e^(1/(R2||R3)C) + Vth

Did I get this right? I'm having doubts because it's an op-amp and i'm not sure if i'm oversimplifying things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal [opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGb9jk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for:

- $$\text{V}_3=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{R}_5\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag5$$
- $$\text{I}_5=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{0 == I1 + I2, I6 == I2 + I3, I3 == I4 + I5, I7 == I4 + I5, 
   I7 == I1 + I6, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (V2 - V1)/R2, 
   I3 == (V2 - V3)/R3, I4 == V3/R4, I5 == V3/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, I7, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/R1, I2 -> -(Vi/R1), 
  I3 -> -((R2 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), 
  I4 -> -((R2 R5 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), 
  I5 -> -((R2 R4 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), 
  I6 -> -((((R2 + R3) R4 + (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) Vi)/(
    R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), 
  I7 -> -((R2 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), 
  V2 -> -((R2 Vi)/R1), 
  V3 -> -((R2 R4 R5 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5))}}
```

In order to calculate the [equivalent Thevenin circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) seen by the resistor \$\text{R}_5\$, we can write:

- For the Thevenin voltage \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\lim_{\text{R}_5\to\infty}\text{V}_3=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag7$$
- For the Thevenin current \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\lim_{\text{R}_5\to0}\text{I}_5=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}\tag8$$
- For the Thevenin resistance \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag9$$

Where I used Mathematica-code, again:

```
In[2]:=Limit[-((R2 R4 R5 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), R5 -> Infinity]

Out[2]=-((R2 R4 Vi)/(R1 R3 + R1 R4))

In[3]:=Limit[-((R2 R4 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), R5 -> 0]

Out[3]=-((R2 Vi)/(R1 R3))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[(-((R2 R4 Vi)/(R1 R3 + R1 R4)))/(-((R2 Vi)/(R1 R3)))]

Out[4]=(R3 R4)/(R3 + R4)
```

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag{10}$$
- The input voltage, \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, is a [Heaviside theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) (because of the [step response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response)):
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\theta\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\tag{11}$$

So, we get for \$\text{V}_3\$ (using \$(5)\$):

$$\text{v}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}}{\text{R}_1\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag{12}$$

Using inverse Laplace transform we get:

$$\text{V}_3\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)t}{\text{C}\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\right)-1\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag{13}$$

Using your values we end up with:

$$\text{V}_3\left(t\right)=\frac{5\left(\exp\left(-75 t\right)-1\right)}{3}=\frac{5}{3}\cdot\left(e^{-75 t}-1\right)\tag{14}$$

Where I used Mathematica-code, again:

```
In[5]:=Vi = 1/s;
R5 = 1/(s*c);
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[-((R2 R4 R5 Vi)/(
   R1 R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4) R5)), s, t]]

Out[5]=((-1 + E^(-(((R3 + R4) t)/(c R3 R4)))) R2 R4)/(R1 (R3 + R4))

In[6]:=R1 = 20000;
R2 = 50000;
R3 = 10000;
R4 = 20000;
c = 2*10^(-6);
FullSimplify[((-1 + E^(-(((R3 + R4) t)/(c R3 R4)))) R2 R4)/(
 R1 (R3 + R4))]

Out[6]=5/3 (-1 + E^(-75 t))
```

Answer (score 1):

When analyzing transfer functions, a good way is to break down the system into blocks. The problem is it looks like the analysis for the opamp was done incorrectly
The s transfer functions look like this:
[image]

Then the total equation would be

K1 is orange
K2 is green
\$ V_{out} = K_1K_2V_{in}\$

As s goes to infinity (as c charges) c ends up with the same voltage
As r3

Comment: And the voltage at R3 will be Vout, right? Also, what would the relationship be of K1 and K2? And how would they affect the output?

Comment: Yes, the voltage at R3 is Vout. K1 and K2 are just gains (from the pic)

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.